# Menus, folders, programs are all hidden or invisible in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: menu

I have had problems with this laptop Aspire 4530 for the last 3 days.

I erased the last Ubuntu (several times) and all is the same: Ubuntu starts, but in the screen there is not a menu (in the left side (using Gnome Desktop)) and I can not see any program, application, internet, graphic, games, nothing. I neither can see any folder.

This is killing me for hours.

Any idea in how can I get those menus back?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem.

I opened a terminal (**Ctrl + Alt + T**) and the **Terminal** opened.

I wrote/pasted this:  **software-center**

and the **Ubuntu Software center** opened.

I searched/installed the **Gnome Shell**.

I restarted and I applied for **Gnome Classic (No Effect)**

That is it.

The Menus (Applications, Places, etc) is back as was in Ubuntu 10.04, etc.

Any refute or comment?

so this thread was solved by me, the Asker.

Just curious,, why this happened? 
Physical problems with the computer?
or
is something new in the new Ubuntu 12.10 and above?